# why this code work in console but not in WebExtensions?

Tags: firefox, document.write

i have this strange behavior in firefox console this code work:

```
var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + "test" + '</h1>');
mywindow.document.write("<p>Ceci est un test</p>");
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
```

but not in my firefox WebExtensions. Why?

Answer (score 0):

done with background script  and messaging